# Programmatically Creating and Populating Multiple Listboxes in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, foreach, listbox

Goal: Create a listbox for each parameter on an SSRS report.

Currently, the code works fine if the report has one parameter.  The idea is that I populate a list of `ValidValue` objects and add the labels to a listbox.  This should happen for each parameter.

How do I programmatically create multiple list boxes, populate them using `foreach` statements, and then add them all to a grid?

Here's my code:

```
        ReportParameterInfoCollection parameters;
        parameters = reportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();
        List<ValidValue> paramList = new List<ValidValue>();
        ListBox boxbox = new ListBox();

        foreach (ReportParameterInfo param in parameters)
        {
            paramList = param.ValidValues.ToList();
            labels.Clear();
            boxbox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (ValidValue val in paramList)
            {
                labels.Add(val.Label + " - " + val.Value);
            }

            foreach (string lab in labels)
            {
                boxbox.Items.Add(lab);
            }

            flyGrid.Children.Add(boxbox);
        }
```

EDIT: See solution below.  For anyone that's curious, I'm trying to get around SSRS's poor UI for parameters and implement my own UI based on what is in the report.

Comment: What happens when you run this? Errors? Nothing?

Comment: It looks like you are clearing your lists for each parameter.  You would need to maintain a list of combobox values, and then when the selected value is changed (either through binding or events), change the labels of the `ValidValue`.  I can't give you any code because I'm not sure what context you are working in.  A possibility would be a `List<string>` and a `List<List<ValidValue>>` or `Dictionary<string, List<ValidValue>>`

Comment: There were no errors; the listboxes would just overwrite each other.  Thank you for the response Matthew.  I ended up solving it in a different way, but I appreciate the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The key was to create a list of ListBox objects, and add a degree of division to the grid each time.  Also, `Grid.SetRow` was required to avoid overlap. Here is the code I ended up using:

```
        List<ListBox> boxList = new List<ListBox>();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();
        List<ValidValue> paramList = new List<ValidValue>();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (ReportParameterInfo param in parameters)
        {
            boxList.Add(new ListBox());
            paramList = param.ValidValues.ToList();
            labels.Clear();
            foreach (ValidValue val in paramList)
            {
                labels.Add(val.Label + " - " + val.Value);
            }

            foreach (string lab in labels)
            {
                boxList[i].Items.Add(lab);
            }

            flyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

            flyGrid.Children.Add(boxList[i]);
            Grid.SetRow(boxList[i], i);
            boxList[i].Margin = new Thickness(20);
            i++;
        }
```